# SQL query result to C# Variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull data from an SQL variable in C# to use in another SQL query.

Basically I have a for loop that is running through a datagrid and inserting the data into a table which I need to be linked to @DataID in this query below.  As it is in a different query I can't access it so I want to pull it out into a var.

What's the best way to go about this? already searched lots of options and not coming up with anything that works

The help is appreciated!

Cheers

```
string dartBoxQuery = @"DECLARE @DataID int;
INSERT INTO DartBox (DartBoxNumber, ReturnDate, Comments)
VALUES (@dbn, @rtndate, @cmmts)
SELECT @DataID = scope_identity();";

// set up the command before exec
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dartBoxQuery, con);

//set parameters
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rtndate", dateTimePicker1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbn", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmmts", textBox2.Text);

// call SQL connection
con.Open();
// execute above query
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//close connection
con.Close();
```

Comment: return your result as DataSet(), Also, your query is not returning any it is just setting scope_identity into a @DataID varialbe

Comment: [Stop using `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @KashifQureshi thanks - could you give me an example please? Really stuck and still learning, appreciated

Comment: @DourHighArch had no idea this was bad, thanks for this

Comment: you can also use OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO #Temp. And then SELECT * FROM #Temp

Comment: @Steve I do have a way to dump that value to another table but I was thinking if multiple users are accessing this will it be ok to do that or will they possibly get an incorrect value if someone else was using this at the same time?

Comment: OUTPUT INSERTED will guarantee to return the id that your inserted statement just inserted. #temp table is only visible to your current session so no race condition possible

Comment: @KashifQureshi it is 2018 - the number of times you should ever use `DataSet` are minimal

Comment: @DourHighArch TBH varchar is the only type that I have experienced problem with AddWithValue. Everything else works fine. The database is smart enough to figure it out

Comment: can I clarify... you just want to get the value of `@DataID` back to the caller?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes I just need that value - it is the unique ID for the other table that my loop writes to.  It is basically just a box and in the loop I have 10-20 serial numbers that I want to put in the box from a grid, but I have to loop through that so can't get @ DataID from the previous query that runs right before it.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch `@DataID` back to the caller, there are 3 options:

- declare an `output` parameter... presumably just moving `@DataID` to be an `output` parameter rather than a local variable; add an extra parameter and give it the direction of `ParameterDirection.Output`; after the `ExecuteNonQuery`, read out the value
- at the end of your existing SQL, `return @DataID`; add an extra parameter and give it the direction of `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`; after the `ExecuteNonQuery`, read out the value
- at the end of your existing SQL, `select @DataID`; use `ExecuteScalar` and read out the return value

In this case, `ExecuteScalar` is probably the easiest option:

```
string dartBoxQuery = @"DECLARE @DataID int;
INSERT INTO DartBox (DartBoxNumber, ReturnDate, Comments)
VALUES (@dbn, @rtndate, @cmmts)
SELECT @DataID = scope_identity();

SELECT @DataID";

// set up the command before exec
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dartBoxQuery, con);

//set parameters
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rtndate", dateTimePicker1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbn", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmmts", textBox2.Text);

// call SQL connection
con.Open();
// execute above query
var dataId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

//close connection
con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Marcgravell this worked perfectly really helpful explaination.  Now I can sleep not thinking about it and start on more tomorrow :))

Comment: @Andy00001 now if I may offer some advice: writing ADO.NET code by hand is painful and hard; I **strongly** recommend tools like "Dapper" for this purpose (I'm biased, note); your calling code becomes **much** easier!

Comment: Thank you I will definitely have a look at this!!